# C# MongoDB driver very slow on text search

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, full-text-search, mongodb-query

I have a wildcard text search over a collection with a million documents.

I can use my full text index directly from the MongoDB console with:

```
 db.oneMillionDocumentsIndexed.find({$text: { $search: "raven" } } )
```

and this returns document after a minute-ish.

When I try the same thing in a unit test though, test runs for over half an hour without returning any documents:

```
[Test]
public void SearchTextFullText()
{
    var credential = MongoCredential.CreateCredential("test", "readonlyUser", "password");
    var settings = new MongoClientSettings
                   {
                       Credentials = new[] { credential },
                       Server = new MongoServerAddress("localhost")
                   };

    var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);

    var database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("test");

    var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("oneMillionDocumentsIndexed");

    var searchWord = "raven";

    var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Text(searchWord);


    var documentCount = 0;


    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    stopwatch.Start();
    using (var cursor = collection.FindAsync(filter).Result)
    {
        while (cursor.MoveNext())  // <-- We never get past this point
        {
            var batch = cursor.Current;

            foreach (var document in batch)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(document["_id"].AsObjectId.ToString());
                Assert.That(document, Is.Not.Null);
                documentCount++;
            }

        }
    }
    stopwatch.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine($"Found {documentCount} documents.  Total time {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms.  Avg. {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / documentCount}");
}
```

**It did finally finish:**  Found 158791 documents.  Total time 1670368ms.  Avg. 10

Do 27mins and 50 seconds.

Comment: Note that the query you are running in the shell is only "returning" the first 25 results from the cursor with what you have listed. Unless you actually include code there to also iterate the cursor, then this is not the same thing. Neither case is really a measure of the "query" itself, where the best measure is with "explain". So in general, when you ask for `158791` documents of indeterminate ( and likely large, due to text ) size, to also be likely transmitted over a network to the client, then that is going to take some time.

Comment: Cheers @BlakesSeven.  I considered that, but typing `it` always returned immediately which makes me think that it's not the cursor (?)

Comment: Another `25` is not `158791`. If you want a fair comparison then you need a loop. i.e `var count = 0; db.oneMillionDocumentsIndexed.find({$text: { $search: "raven" } } ).forEach(function(doc) { printjson(doc); count++ }); print(count);`

Comment: I'll try that, thanks!  (possibly without the `printjson` though as I know that printing adds magnitudes of overhead.)

Comment: Overhead that is evident in your C# listing. Apples with apples.

Comment: What do you mean?  I'm not printing, just null checking.  I might be missing something though.

Comment: Ignore that!  I can see it.  Yes, that was added after the fact to see if stuff was doing anything!

Answer (score 1):

Task.Result is a blocking call (in this case collection.FindAsync(filter).Result), it will wait until full result set is computed and then it will return.

you can try this code and i'm sure it will perform better (though not tested)

```
using(var cursor = await collection.Find(filter).ToCursorAsync())
{
    while(await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
    {
        //rest of logic ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of mongoDb driver you use but can you try this

```
 while (cursor.MoveNextAsync().Result)
```

Comment: I'll give that a go.